# How to repeat an sprite in CSS as background

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-sprites

I have a problem, which i can't find how to solve, i need to make an sprite as a background of a container.

The problem is that i can't figure out how to make it, i have search about this but i couldn't find anything to help me to solve this.

The sprite i want to use as  background start in the coordinates x=144px y=288px

so far the only what i get is the whole image repeat it everytime.

```css
.main {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfC2Pus.png");
    background-position: -144px -288px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum beatae corrupti minus consequuntur, facere cupiditate deserunt maxime id non nihil praesentium voluptas at ea similique nemo nobis recusandae soluta vitae voluptatibus quisquam. Impedit sapiente non aut, voluptates assumenda fugit soluta labore ut nulla natus, reiciendis hic laborum beatae blanditiis facilis officiis est iste. Tempora cumque voluptatem enim voluptatibus asperiores, minima tempore quidem reiciendis explicabo sapiente quae inventore ipsa. Distinctio officia dicta quos nihil eum quisquam, ipsum odio deserunt quam non perferendis eos, obcaecati illo vero iure dignissimos velit. Velit ipsam corporis, officiis quas unde facere id tempora minima beatae, dicta, magni sed quaerat architecto, animi a eum veritatis. Iste veniam suscipit quam molestiae cupiditate magni ex error minus, ut maiores! Deleniti numquam, voluptatibus incidunt! Perspiciatis laudantium facere ullam quibusdam velit sed eos, reiciendis enim vitae veniam temporibus nulla repudiandae commodi, expedita cumque eligendi. Laboriosam voluptatem, in praesentium atque at, soluta. Magni sunt tempore tenetur, ullam nihil labore repellat nulla ad voluptates doloremque suscipit veniam architecto quod eius eveniet omnis facilis libero officiis, animi sequi placeat repellendus dicta, enim dolorum numquam. Velit dicta vitae, maxime ipsa facilis impedit dignissimos distinctio voluptatibus modi, deleniti necessitatibus exercitationem, earum porro. Illum, provident deserunt pariatur.</p>
    <p>Id, autem? Officiis nesciunt eaque dolorum, omnis, voluptatum sit voluptas aspernatur delectus tempora explicabo cum ipsa eum aperiam veritatis nam sapiente, illum. Quos voluptatem quod illo, quas tenetur excepturi ea reiciendis dolore voluptatum? Similique reprehenderit ea laboriosam. Reprehenderit nemo velit suscipit consequatur esse, voluptate itaque vel eveniet alias placeat mollitia dolorem quibusdam adipisci repellat voluptatem neque, numquam quam! Recusandae temporibus asperiores aut odit, eum quam consectetur aspernatur saepe earum impedit, alias quae consequatur tempore labore facilis doloribus ut adipisci magni. Cum est harum quibusdam veritatis aspernatur esse iusto inventore a asperiores rem, facilis vel expedita quaerat magni vero id neque. Dolorum assumenda amet incidunt molestias perferendis a dolore distinctio dignissimos esse quam ipsam debitis fugit, ipsa, officia sed, facilis, cum quibusdam tenetur quas? Officiis nihil libero expedita odio doloremque, beatae, praesentium voluptatem provident amet fugit dicta aliquid. Esse consequuntur labore et beatae cum maiores, itaque ducimus atque, rerum, inventore laboriosam nobis illo, non facilis quisquam sunt provident cumque nemo. Debitis odit reprehenderit officia recusandae, deserunt, id impedit, distinctio incidunt nemo non est velit eaque nulla tempore repellendus sed quod facere. Nostrum non, atque, suscipit incidunt placeat aspernatur impedit, earum nemo quidem molestiae dolore. Nemo totam id eos ab maxime minima.</p>
    <p>Cum veniam, provident culpa enim eum magni ut maxime quae sint earum beatae minus delectus dolorum pariatur cupiditate voluptas aperiam, libero magnam. Nostrum ea architecto deleniti illo quibusdam quisquam, alias harum, ducimus possimus molestias perspiciatis dolorum nemo, blanditiis cupiditate exercitationem corporis ab eligendi sit itaque nihil laboriosam quos saepe quas? Commodi id dolorem debitis consequuntur nihil voluptates culpa temporibus iusto eligendi! Maxime quidem cupiditate quam corrupti blanditiis exercitationem dolore distinctio fugiat temporibus quas quibusdam totam quos eligendi et necessitatibus, dolor inventore culpa eveniet odit obcaecati mollitia modi? Sequi, quia, tenetur. Est pariatur minima adipisci, minus, culpa sit consequatur, fugit aperiam sint amet voluptatibus hic! Nesciunt cumque voluptate, velit saepe sunt numquam quam repellat accusamus in. Voluptas quod tempora omnis nobis quibusdam architecto, delectus quaerat nulla velit expedita error cumque distinctio non magnam repellat, odit laudantium similique voluptatibus totam, unde, voluptatum laboriosam. Qui repudiandae velit fugiat doloribus alias vero ipsa maxime voluptas saepe quis non laborum quae voluptates et minima nihil architecto earum, vel nemo maiores reiciendis! Autem velit vitae alias dolores saepe fugit sequi molestias, aspernatur quo delectus doloremque nihil obcaecati asperiores amet, id omnis ullam neque. Earum sed dicta perspiciatis, consectetur incidunt voluptatibus vel, omnis minus odit, aliquam nulla.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what i want, is what i post here below, but instead of using an image, i want to use a specific sprite inside an image.

```css
.main {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/2OqgNaO.png");
/*    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfC2Pus.png"); */
/*    background-position: -144px -288px;  */
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum beatae corrupti minus consequuntur, facere cupiditate deserunt maxime id non nihil praesentium voluptas at ea similique nemo nobis recusandae soluta vitae voluptatibus quisquam. Impedit sapiente non aut, voluptates assumenda fugit soluta labore ut nulla natus, reiciendis hic laborum beatae blanditiis facilis officiis est iste. Tempora cumque voluptatem enim voluptatibus asperiores, minima tempore quidem reiciendis explicabo sapiente quae inventore ipsa. Distinctio officia dicta quos nihil eum quisquam, ipsum odio deserunt quam non perferendis eos, obcaecati illo vero iure dignissimos velit. Velit ipsam corporis, officiis quas unde facere id tempora minima beatae, dicta, magni sed quaerat architecto, animi a eum veritatis. Iste veniam suscipit quam molestiae cupiditate magni ex error minus, ut maiores! Deleniti numquam, voluptatibus incidunt! Perspiciatis laudantium facere ullam quibusdam velit sed eos, reiciendis enim vitae veniam temporibus nulla repudiandae commodi, expedita cumque eligendi. Laboriosam voluptatem, in praesentium atque at, soluta. Magni sunt tempore tenetur, ullam nihil labore repellat nulla ad voluptates doloremque suscipit veniam architecto quod eius eveniet omnis facilis libero officiis, animi sequi placeat repellendus dicta, enim dolorum numquam. Velit dicta vitae, maxime ipsa facilis impedit dignissimos distinctio voluptatibus modi, deleniti necessitatibus exercitationem, earum porro. Illum, provident deserunt pariatur.</p>
    <p>Id, autem? Officiis nesciunt eaque dolorum, omnis, voluptatum sit voluptas aspernatur delectus tempora explicabo cum ipsa eum aperiam veritatis nam sapiente, illum. Quos voluptatem quod illo, quas tenetur excepturi ea reiciendis dolore voluptatum? Similique reprehenderit ea laboriosam. Reprehenderit nemo velit suscipit consequatur esse, voluptate itaque vel eveniet alias placeat mollitia dolorem quibusdam adipisci repellat voluptatem neque, numquam quam! Recusandae temporibus asperiores aut odit, eum quam consectetur aspernatur saepe earum impedit, alias quae consequatur tempore labore facilis doloribus ut adipisci magni. Cum est harum quibusdam veritatis aspernatur esse iusto inventore a asperiores rem, facilis vel expedita quaerat magni vero id neque. Dolorum assumenda amet incidunt molestias perferendis a dolore distinctio dignissimos esse quam ipsam debitis fugit, ipsa, officia sed, facilis, cum quibusdam tenetur quas? Officiis nihil libero expedita odio doloremque, beatae, praesentium voluptatem provident amet fugit dicta aliquid. Esse consequuntur labore et beatae cum maiores, itaque ducimus atque, rerum, inventore laboriosam nobis illo, non facilis quisquam sunt provident cumque nemo. Debitis odit reprehenderit officia recusandae, deserunt, id impedit, distinctio incidunt nemo non est velit eaque nulla tempore repellendus sed quod facere. Nostrum non, atque, suscipit incidunt placeat aspernatur impedit, earum nemo quidem molestiae dolore. Nemo totam id eos ab maxime minima.</p>
    <p>Cum veniam, provident culpa enim eum magni ut maxime quae sint earum beatae minus delectus dolorum pariatur cupiditate voluptas aperiam, libero magnam. Nostrum ea architecto deleniti illo quibusdam quisquam, alias harum, ducimus possimus molestias perspiciatis dolorum nemo, blanditiis cupiditate exercitationem corporis ab eligendi sit itaque nihil laboriosam quos saepe quas? Commodi id dolorem debitis consequuntur nihil voluptates culpa temporibus iusto eligendi! Maxime quidem cupiditate quam corrupti blanditiis exercitationem dolore distinctio fugiat temporibus quas quibusdam totam quos eligendi et necessitatibus, dolor inventore culpa eveniet odit obcaecati mollitia modi? Sequi, quia, tenetur. Est pariatur minima adipisci, minus, culpa sit consequatur, fugit aperiam sint amet voluptatibus hic! Nesciunt cumque voluptate, velit saepe sunt numquam quam repellat accusamus in. Voluptas quod tempora omnis nobis quibusdam architecto, delectus quaerat nulla velit expedita error cumque distinctio non magnam repellat, odit laudantium similique voluptatibus totam, unde, voluptatum laboriosam. Qui repudiandae velit fugiat doloribus alias vero ipsa maxime voluptas saepe quis non laborum quae voluptates et minima nihil architecto earum, vel nemo maiores reiciendis! Autem velit vitae alias dolores saepe fugit sequi molestias, aspernatur quo delectus doloremque nihil obcaecati asperiores amet, id omnis ullam neque. Earum sed dicta perspiciatis, consectetur incidunt voluptatibus vel, omnis minus odit, aliquam nulla.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.main {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfC2Pus.png");
    background-position: -144px -288px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum beatae corrupti minus consequuntur, facere cupiditate deserunt maxime id non nihil praesentium voluptas at ea similique nemo nobis recusandae soluta vitae voluptatibus quisquam. Impedit sapiente non aut, voluptates assumenda fugit soluta labore ut nulla natus, reiciendis hic laborum beatae blanditiis facilis officiis est iste. Tempora cumque voluptatem enim voluptatibus asperiores, minima tempore quidem reiciendis explicabo sapiente quae inventore ipsa. Distinctio officia dicta quos nihil eum quisquam, ipsum odio deserunt quam non perferendis eos, obcaecati illo vero iure dignissimos velit. Velit ipsam corporis, officiis quas unde facere id tempora minima beatae, dicta, magni sed quaerat architecto, animi a eum veritatis. Iste veniam suscipit quam molestiae cupiditate magni ex error minus, ut maiores! Deleniti numquam, voluptatibus incidunt! Perspiciatis laudantium facere ullam quibusdam velit sed eos, reiciendis enim vitae veniam temporibus nulla repudiandae commodi, expedita cumque eligendi. Laboriosam voluptatem, in praesentium atque at, soluta. Magni sunt tempore tenetur, ullam nihil labore repellat nulla ad voluptates doloremque suscipit veniam architecto quod eius eveniet omnis facilis libero officiis, animi sequi placeat repellendus dicta, enim dolorum numquam. Velit dicta vitae, maxime ipsa facilis impedit dignissimos distinctio voluptatibus modi, deleniti necessitatibus exercitationem, earum porro. Illum, provident deserunt pariatur.</p>
    <p>Id, autem? Officiis nesciunt eaque dolorum, omnis, voluptatum sit voluptas aspernatur delectus tempora explicabo cum ipsa eum aperiam veritatis nam sapiente, illum. Quos voluptatem quod illo, quas tenetur excepturi ea reiciendis dolore voluptatum? Similique reprehenderit ea laboriosam. Reprehenderit nemo velit suscipit consequatur esse, voluptate itaque vel eveniet alias placeat mollitia dolorem quibusdam adipisci repellat voluptatem neque, numquam quam! Recusandae temporibus asperiores aut odit, eum quam consectetur aspernatur saepe earum impedit, alias quae consequatur tempore labore facilis doloribus ut adipisci magni. Cum est harum quibusdam veritatis aspernatur esse iusto inventore a asperiores rem, facilis vel expedita quaerat magni vero id neque. Dolorum assumenda amet incidunt molestias perferendis a dolore distinctio dignissimos esse quam ipsam debitis fugit, ipsa, officia sed, facilis, cum quibusdam tenetur quas? Officiis nihil libero expedita odio doloremque, beatae, praesentium voluptatem provident amet fugit dicta aliquid. Esse consequuntur labore et beatae cum maiores, itaque ducimus atque, rerum, inventore laboriosam nobis illo, non facilis quisquam sunt provident cumque nemo. Debitis odit reprehenderit officia recusandae, deserunt, id impedit, distinctio incidunt nemo non est velit eaque nulla tempore repellendus sed quod facere. Nostrum non, atque, suscipit incidunt placeat aspernatur impedit, earum nemo quidem molestiae dolore. Nemo totam id eos ab maxime minima.</p>
    <p>Cum veniam, provident culpa enim eum magni ut maxime quae sint earum beatae minus delectus dolorum pariatur cupiditate voluptas aperiam, libero magnam. Nostrum ea architecto deleniti illo quibusdam quisquam, alias harum, ducimus possimus molestias perspiciatis dolorum nemo, blanditiis cupiditate exercitationem corporis ab eligendi sit itaque nihil laboriosam quos saepe quas? Commodi id dolorem debitis consequuntur nihil voluptates culpa temporibus iusto eligendi! Maxime quidem cupiditate quam corrupti blanditiis exercitationem dolore distinctio fugiat temporibus quas quibusdam totam quos eligendi et necessitatibus, dolor inventore culpa eveniet odit obcaecati mollitia modi? Sequi, quia, tenetur. Est pariatur minima adipisci, minus, culpa sit consequatur, fugit aperiam sint amet voluptatibus hic! Nesciunt cumque voluptate, velit saepe sunt numquam quam repellat accusamus in. Voluptas quod tempora omnis nobis quibusdam architecto, delectus quaerat nulla velit expedita error cumque distinctio non magnam repellat, odit laudantium similique voluptatibus totam, unde, voluptatum laboriosam. Qui repudiandae velit fugiat doloribus alias vero ipsa maxime voluptas saepe quis non laborum quae voluptates et minima nihil architecto earum, vel nemo maiores reiciendis! Autem velit vitae alias dolores saepe fugit sequi molestias, aspernatur quo delectus doloremque nihil obcaecati asperiores amet, id omnis ullam neque. Earum sed dicta perspiciatis, consectetur incidunt voluptatibus vel, omnis minus odit, aliquam nulla.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you starting the image off screen? The negative numbers are going left and up in that order. So you are starting left 144px and up 288 px beyond the viewports dimensions. Is that what you want?        `background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;` **I dont know what you are trying to accomplish?**

Comment: Plus that image is like 4 images in 1...not a very good image to test with. Are you trying just to utilize a piece of the image? Like just the moon portion? Maybe just the stars? You would be better off in that case pulling it into photoshop and cropping it how you need it. Don't fight it if you do not have to. Hell I'll do it for you xD

Comment: Is an sprite i want to make that the image that looks like a star night be repeated in horizontal and vertical, just that sprite.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `background-repeat: no-repeat;` declaration in your CSS. Then you can adjust your `background-position` and `background-size` to the correct position.

```css
.main {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfC2Pus.png");
    background-position: -144px -288px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum beatae corrupti minus consequuntur, facere cupiditate deserunt maxime id non nihil praesentium voluptas at ea similique nemo nobis recusandae soluta vitae voluptatibus quisquam. Impedit sapiente non aut, voluptates assumenda fugit soluta labore ut nulla natus, reiciendis hic laborum beatae blanditiis facilis officiis est iste. Tempora cumque voluptatem enim voluptatibus asperiores, minima tempore quidem reiciendis explicabo sapiente quae inventore ipsa. Distinctio officia dicta quos nihil eum quisquam, ipsum odio deserunt quam non perferendis eos, obcaecati illo vero iure dignissimos velit. Velit ipsam corporis, officiis quas unde facere id tempora minima beatae, dicta, magni sed quaerat architecto, animi a eum veritatis. Iste veniam suscipit quam molestiae cupiditate magni ex error minus, ut maiores! Deleniti numquam, voluptatibus incidunt! Perspiciatis laudantium facere ullam quibusdam velit sed eos, reiciendis enim vitae veniam temporibus nulla repudiandae commodi, expedita cumque eligendi. Laboriosam voluptatem, in praesentium atque at, soluta. Magni sunt tempore tenetur, ullam nihil labore repellat nulla ad voluptates doloremque suscipit veniam architecto quod eius eveniet omnis facilis libero officiis, animi sequi placeat repellendus dicta, enim dolorum numquam. Velit dicta vitae, maxime ipsa facilis impedit dignissimos distinctio voluptatibus modi, deleniti necessitatibus exercitationem, earum porro. Illum, provident deserunt pariatur.</p>
    <p>Id, autem? Officiis nesciunt eaque dolorum, omnis, voluptatum sit voluptas aspernatur delectus tempora explicabo cum ipsa eum aperiam veritatis nam sapiente, illum. Quos voluptatem quod illo, quas tenetur excepturi ea reiciendis dolore voluptatum? Similique reprehenderit ea laboriosam. Reprehenderit nemo velit suscipit consequatur esse, voluptate itaque vel eveniet alias placeat mollitia dolorem quibusdam adipisci repellat voluptatem neque, numquam quam! Recusandae temporibus asperiores aut odit, eum quam consectetur aspernatur saepe earum impedit, alias quae consequatur tempore labore facilis doloribus ut adipisci magni. Cum est harum quibusdam veritatis aspernatur esse iusto inventore a asperiores rem, facilis vel expedita quaerat magni vero id neque. Dolorum assumenda amet incidunt molestias perferendis a dolore distinctio dignissimos esse quam ipsam debitis fugit, ipsa, officia sed, facilis, cum quibusdam tenetur quas? Officiis nihil libero expedita odio doloremque, beatae, praesentium voluptatem provident amet fugit dicta aliquid. Esse consequuntur labore et beatae cum maiores, itaque ducimus atque, rerum, inventore laboriosam nobis illo, non facilis quisquam sunt provident cumque nemo. Debitis odit reprehenderit officia recusandae, deserunt, id impedit, distinctio incidunt nemo non est velit eaque nulla tempore repellendus sed quod facere. Nostrum non, atque, suscipit incidunt placeat aspernatur impedit, earum nemo quidem molestiae dolore. Nemo totam id eos ab maxime minima.</p>
    <p>Cum veniam, provident culpa enim eum magni ut maxime quae sint earum beatae minus delectus dolorum pariatur cupiditate voluptas aperiam, libero magnam. Nostrum ea architecto deleniti illo quibusdam quisquam, alias harum, ducimus possimus molestias perspiciatis dolorum nemo, blanditiis cupiditate exercitationem corporis ab eligendi sit itaque nihil laboriosam quos saepe quas? Commodi id dolorem debitis consequuntur nihil voluptates culpa temporibus iusto eligendi! Maxime quidem cupiditate quam corrupti blanditiis exercitationem dolore distinctio fugiat temporibus quas quibusdam totam quos eligendi et necessitatibus, dolor inventore culpa eveniet odit obcaecati mollitia modi? Sequi, quia, tenetur. Est pariatur minima adipisci, minus, culpa sit consequatur, fugit aperiam sint amet voluptatibus hic! Nesciunt cumque voluptate, velit saepe sunt numquam quam repellat accusamus in. Voluptas quod tempora omnis nobis quibusdam architecto, delectus quaerat nulla velit expedita error cumque distinctio non magnam repellat, odit laudantium similique voluptatibus totam, unde, voluptatum laboriosam. Qui repudiandae velit fugiat doloribus alias vero ipsa maxime voluptas saepe quis non laborum quae voluptates et minima nihil architecto earum, vel nemo maiores reiciendis! Autem velit vitae alias dolores saepe fugit sequi molestias, aspernatur quo delectus doloremque nihil obcaecati asperiores amet, id omnis ullam neque. Earum sed dicta perspiciatis, consectetur incidunt voluptatibus vel, omnis minus odit, aliquam nulla.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but is not what i want, that this sprite: http://i.imgur.com/2OqgNaO.png fill the entire content of the block as background.